# Limit the Wordpress function notification email sent to one

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I have this function that fires every 3 minutes to check if a plugin is inactive and sends an email to me if it is inactive:

```
if ( ! function_exists('is_plugin_inactive')) {
require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
}

if (is_plugin_inactive( 'pluginfolder/plugin.php' )) {

function isa_add_cron_recurrence_interval( $schedules ) {

$schedules['every_three_minutes'] = array(
        'interval'  => 180,
        'display'   => __( 'Every 3 Minutes', 'textdomain' )
);

return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'isa_add_cron_recurrence_interval' );
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_three_minutes', 
'your_three_minute_action_hook' );
add_action('your_three_minute_action_hook', 
'isa_test_cron_job_send_mail');

function isa_test_cron_job_send_mail() {

//plugin is not activated
$to = 'me@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Plugin Inactive';
$body = 'PANIC!';
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
}
}
```

It floods me with a notification emails every time it runs.
How do I limit the email to send once per firing?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The cron will run every 3 minutes and send an email, this is how you set it up. How do you mean it should run once per firing?

Comment: When the cron runs ( every 3 mins. ) it sends a bunch of emails to me every time it runs. I just want it to send one email per cron job.

Comment: Ok I understand. So in your if statement to check if the plugin is inactive, how many plugins are you checking for? Is it just 1?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, Yes just one, more maybe a very short list

Comment: that's probably why you are getting multiple notifications, it's checking if each plugin is inactive and then sending an email for each.

Comment: ok so targeting the plugin with :      if (is_plugin_inactive( 'pluginfolder/plugin.php' ))  isn't going to do the trick?

Comment: It is going to work but it’s going to send an email for each inactive plugin, if that makes sense. For example if you are checking for 3 plugins, it’s going to send the email 3 times every 3 minutes or if you are checking 6 plugins, it will send 6 emails every 3 minutes etc.